# How can I view log files in Linux and apply custom filters while viewing?

Tags: linux, filter, logfiles

I need to read through some gigantic log files on a Linux system.  There's a lot of clutter in the logs.  At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
cat logfile.txt | grep -v "IgnoreThis\|IgnoreThat" | less
```

But it's cumbersome -- every time I want to add another filter, I need to quit `less` and edit the command line.  Some of the filters are relatively complicated and may be multi-line.

I'd like some way to apply filters as I am reading through the log, and a way to save these filters somewhere.

Is there a tool that can do this for me?  I can't install new software so hopefully it's something that would already be installed -- e.g., less, vi, something in a Python or Perl lib, etc.

Changing the code that generates the log to generate less is not an option.

Comment: I don't have a magic wand for you, but this might be beter on serverfault.com...

Comment: @Peter -- good suggestion: http://serverfault.com/questions/117013/how-can-i-view-log-files-in-linux-and-apply-custom-filers-while-viewing

Comment: Note that it's considered bad style to start a pipeline with `cat FILE | ...`.  Better would be `grep args < FILE | ...` or just `grep args FILE | ...`

Comment: @RSK: Normally I would do something like that, but in reality I have a bunch of grep's piped together and it seemed silly to write: `grep -v "OneFilter" < FILE | grep -v "AnotherUglyLongFilter" | grep -v "etc." | less` ... I guess just because it buries the filename a bit more.

Comment: Actually the style of using `cat FILE | grep .. | awk ... | sort` is more clear. The problem is not style, it is performance, as this way one more process is created and more inter-process communication happens. This is usually no problem for interactive commands, but in scripts the more ugly form should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) tool - as well as letting you view multile logs at once, I'm pretty sure it lets you apply regex filters interactively.

Comment: That looks great... unfortunately not installed.  Maybe I'll have to beg the sysadmin.

Answer (score 115):

Use `&pattern` command within less.

From the man page for less

> &pattern
>
> ```
>           Display  only  lines which match the pattern; lines which do not
>           match the pattern are not displayed.  If pattern  is  empty  (if
>           you  type  &  immediately  followed  by ENTER), any filtering is
>           turned off, and all lines are displayed.  While filtering is  in
>           effect,  an  ampersand  is  displayed  at  the  beginning of the
>           prompt, as a reminder that some lines in the file may be hidden.
>
>           Certain characters are special as in the / command:
>
>           ^N or !
>                  Display only lines which do NOT match the pattern.
>
>           ^R     Don't interpret regular expression  metacharacters;  that
>                  is, do a simple textual comparison.
> ```

Comment: Neat feature.  Not helpful for what I was doing 2 years ago but I'll definitely use that one in the future!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for when I found this question. And I think it's exactly what the question owner asked for. This should be the accepted answer! Anyway, many thanks, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @krookedking upgrade to a newer version of less. I had the same problem and upgraded with `brew install less`, got version 458 which support it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [ghostdog74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338812/how-can-i-view-log-files-in-linux-and-apply-custom-filers-while-viewing/2338853#2338853) and the `less` manpage, I came up with this:

### `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LESSOPEN='|~/less-filter.sh %s'
export LESS=-R  # to allow ANSI colors
```

---

### `~/less-filter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
*logfile*.log*) ~/less-filter.sed < $1
  ;;
esac
```

---

### `~/less-filter.sed`:

```
/deleteLinesLikeThis/d  # to filter out lines
s/this/that/  # to change text on lines (useful to colorize using ANSI escapes)
```

---

Then:

- `less logfileFooBar.log.1` -- applies the filter applies automatically.
- `cat logfileFooBar.log.1 | less` -- to see the log without filtering

This is adequate for now but I would still like to be able to edit the filters on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

see the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) of less. there are some options you can use to search for words for example. It has line editing mode as well.

Comment: I need to filter, not search.  The INPUT PREPROCESSOR may be helpful, although it's not as dynamic as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There's an application by Casstor Software Solutions called LogFilter (www.casstor.com) that can edit Windows/Mac/Linux text files and can easily perform file filtering.  It supports multiple filters as well as regular expressions.  I think it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: That link points to something else entirely now.