# psql displaying ansi colored text

Tags: postgresql, shell, terminal, psql, less-unix

My `.psqlrc` has following options

```
\setenv LESS '-iMSx4 -FXR'
\setenv PAGER 'less'
\pset pager always
```

and psql output which I want to be colored is

```
 {                                                                    +
    \x1B[35m"\x1B[0m\x1B[35mr\x1B[0m\x1B[35m"\x1B[0m: [               +
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m1\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m2\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m3\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m4\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m5\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m6\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m7\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m,+
       \x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m\x1B[32m8\x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[92m"\x1B[0m +
    ]                                                                 +
 }
```

Is there a way to make pager aware of `\x1B` ansi sequences, or to tell `psql` not to convert them to hexadecimal representations when displaying?

Output should look like,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `less` pager can be told to *filter* its input files using the `LESSOPEN` environment variable.

For your case, that could be the name of a script which changes all of `\x1B` to the ASCII escape character, e.g.,

```
sed -e 's/\x1B/^[/'
```

(where the `^[` is a literal <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> character: using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> when inserting with a text editor helps).

Further reading:

- [Unix Lesson - Displaying more with "less"](http://ref.web.cern.ch/ref/CERN/CNL/2002/001/unix-less/)
- [How can I view log files in Linux and apply custom filters while viewing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338812/how-can-i-view-log-files-in-linux-and-apply-custom-filters-while-viewing)
- [less(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/less.1.html) manual page

Per comment: if `psql` calls the pager via a pipe, bypassing `LESSOPEN` (which works given a *file*), you should set your pager to a script which does the combination of filtering and paging, e.g., a script something like

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -pe "s|\\\(x..)|chr(hex(\$1))|ge" | less -iMSx4 -FXR
```

since `perl` works from a pipe if no filenames are given.

**EDIT:**

Solution without external script using `psql` only,

```
\setenv LESS '-iMSx4 -FXR'
\setenv PAGER 'perl -pe \'s|\\\\(x..)|chr(hex($1))|ge\' | less'
```

Comment: Tnx, this works for me `export LESSOPEN='|perl -pe "s|\\\(x..)|chr(hex(\$1))|ge" %s'`

Comment: Unfortunately it works only under shell, but not when using `psql`.

Comment: If you put the command into a script, you can bypass problems with escaping and quoting.

Comment: It's not problem with escaping as psql invokes `less` via pipe, and I've noticed that LESSOPEN doesn't work in such case, ie. `cat ansi_file.txt | less -r` while `less -r ansi_file.txt` works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

An "all-in-one" `psql` solution:

```sh
\o | sed -r 's/\\x1B\[([0-9]+)m/\x1B[\1m/g' | less -R
```

That's it --- no other `psql` or shell commands required.

***How It Works***

- **`\o`**     <===   Gives us direct control of `stdout`.
- **`| sed -r 's/\\x1B\[([0-9]+)m/\x1B[\1m/g'`**     <===   We re-print all the escape sequences exactly as they were, but now interpreted *as themselves and not as literals*.
- **`| less -R`**     <===   We hand the result over to `less(1)` explicitly (`psql` isn't going to do it for us, because we took over control of `stdout`!).  The options to be given to `less(1)` are up to you; as long as they include `-R` (or `-r`), colorization will happen.

---

Works for output of both `SELECT`s and of `\echo` meta-commands.