# Ansible Tower/AWX: Location of job results in PostgreSQL

Tags: ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm trying to get `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of a specific task from the PostgreSQL database to use it in a commit comment.

I have difficulty with finding the right table. Has anyone tried to get a specific task results,  `STDOUT` and `STDERR` from Ansible Tower/AWX?

Am I barking at the right tree?

Answer (score 1):

every task has its own output in the column `stdout` of the table `main_jobevent`.

```
prepare awx (text, int) as
select job_id, host_name, modified, playbook, play, role, stdout
  from main_jobevent
 where host_name = ANY (string_to_array($1, ','))
   and changed
 order by modified desc
 limit $2;

execute awx( 'localhost,192.168.1.1', 3 );
```

this shows the three youngest modifications of the host localhost or 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ansible tower API to get the job stdout. Eg:
https:///api/v2/jobs//stdout/?format=json

Check Ansible Tower API doc
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.2.4/pdf/AnsibleTowerAPIGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According the [Tower API Reference Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html) **Jobs** it is possible to get the full job result log via REST API call as plain text, in example

```
curl --silent -u ${TOWER_USER}:${TOWER_PASSWORD} -JL https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/jobs/${JobID}/stdout?format=txt_download -o job_${JobID}.log
```

resulting into the output of a file called `job_${JobID}.log`. But there is no direct call for specific tasks of job.

As in [maletin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27239/maletin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55545292/6771046) already mentioned, one could gather specific task information from a job by `JobID`

```sql
SELECT job_id, host_name, modified, stdout
FROM main_jobevent 
WHERE job_id = $1
ORDER BY modified ASC;
```

but it looks like [ANSI colored text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867304/).